# jurabib style bibliography versus body or footnote

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, footnotes, jurabib

I know jurabib isn't today's jam and I should use biblatex.  However, biblatex isn't very well integrated with LyX yet, as far as I can tell and Jurabib works quite fine out of the box apart from those changes I would like to achieve:

- the french layout adds spaces before colons and punctuation marks, which is fine generally but not necessarily for citations and *absolutely not for english citation titles*!  I guess the code below has some leak that makes babel french mess with the references (both types, body/footnote AND bibliography styles), it treats the citations as normal text is needs to process in (I don't want any spaces to be added although I appreciate the strictly bibliographical processings like 'and' or 'et' for multiple authors).  How to prevent bibtex or juralib from adding that extra space in the citations ?
- why does the juralib setup (\jurabibsetup) applies sometimes only to the citation style in the body or footnote (namely titleformat and authorformat), and otherwise only to the bibliography/references part (namely dotafter=bibentry)?  Is there a way to tweak this style or do I have to create a new one on my own?

(code updated)

```
%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[french]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@BOOK{Binet2006[1887],
  title={Le Magn{\'e}tisme animal : {\'E}tudes sur l'hypnose},
  publisher={l'Harmattan},
  year={2006 [1887]},
  author={Alfred Binet and Charles F{\'e}r{\'e}},
  pages={283 pages}
}

@BOOK{Collins1992[1985],
  title={Changing Order: Replication and Induction in Scientific Practice},
  publisher={University of Chicago Press},
  year={1992 [1985]},
  author={Harry Collins},
  edition={New edition}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\makeatother
\usepackage{jurabib}[2004/01/25]

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\jurabibsetup{
authorformat={allreversed,and},
citefull=first,
dotafter=bibentry,
titleformat={commasep,italic},
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{Binet2006[1887]}

\cite{Collins1992[1985]}

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibliography{file}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: The second question has been cleared -- I figured out how to fix the bib style, I just RTFM carefully and I am happy with,
    \renewcommand{\bibtfont}{\textit}
    \renewcommand{\bibansep}{, }
    \renewcommand{\bibatsep}{, }
    \renewcommand{\bibbdsep}{, } Now I still need to figure out how to prevent bibtex or jurabib from adding a space before a colon in an english title.  The language = parameter within the bib file doesn't seem to help although it is supposed to be supported.