# Spacing by language in jurabib bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibtex, jurabib

Note that I am still using `jurabib` because it interacts very well with LyX. I can use the citation button (`\cite`) and thanks to `jurabib`'s "citefull" feature I still get full citations in footnotes. Think of `bibentry` or similar feature with `biblatex`.

My previous question has been partially solved as I noted in [my comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144850/jurabib-style-bibliography-versus-body-or-footnote), so instead of editing it once again here's the (only) issue left:

How to prevent BibTeX or `jurabib` from adding a space before a colon or puncuation mark in both, bibliography and (full) citation text?  I tried adding "language =" in the `.bib` file - both english and french are supported, says the jurabib guide - but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: As far as I know biblatex works fine with LyX. On the other side: debugging/adapting jurabib is a pain: It can take hours without knowing if you really can find a solution. I would spent the time to get biblatex working - and if something is missing: make a feature request for LyX.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike.  I am trying biblatex on LyX but [it isn't going well yet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144959/lyx-not-showing-biblatex-printbibliography)