# Bibliography not showing with classicthesis LyX v-4.2

Tags: biblatex, lyx, classicthesis

I am trying to switch to classicthesis style in LyX but the bibliography is not showing in pdf. 
I downloaded the classicthesis-LyX-v4-2 package, opened a new file from template.lyx and everything worked fine until the bibliography part. I added the following to the latex pramble:

\addbibresource{MasteCite}

\addbibresource{Bibliography}

Please help, I have deadline for my master thesis in two weeks and I really liked the classicthesis style.

Comment: You need to include the file ending when using `\addbibresource`, so it should be `\addbibresource{MasteCite.bib}`. But other than that, I can't say much without seeing the code and error messages/logs. Do you load `biblatex`, do you have a `\printbibliography`? Do you run Biber? What errors do you get? Please prepare an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: Please read http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex carefully before you continue. Read also [LyX not showing biblatex \printbibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144959/35864), [BibLatex keep producing errors in Lyx 2.1.4 with MikTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267696/35864) and [BibLaTeX in LyX 2.1.0 with MiKTex on Windows 7: ! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184022/35864)

Comment: @moewe Just checked the template, it uses backend `bibtex8`. This template business is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Johannes_B I could almost here you cry out loud when I read `template.lyx` and `classicthesis` `;-)` ... Apparently `lassicthesis-config.tex` has the `backend=biber` commented out, so they were almost there.

Comment: As @Johannes_B points out your template uses `backend=bibtex8` by default. You should probably change that by going to line 84 of `classicthesis-config.tex`, un-commenting `backend=biber` and in turn commenting out line 85 with `backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%`. Then follow the instructions in the links above.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{
    backend=biber, 
 %instead of bibtex
    %backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    language=auto,%
    style=numeric-comp,%
    %style=philosophy-modern,%
    %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
    %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
    sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
    %backref=true,%
    natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
`

Comment: I got this error now: ´  \addbibresource
                    {MasteCite.bib}
The package biblatex has already been loaded with options:
  [backend=biber,language=auto,style=numeric-comp,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=10,na
tbib=true,]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [style=authoryear,backend=biber]
Adding the global options:
  backend=biber,language=auto,style=numeric-comp,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=10,nat
bib=true,,style=authoryear,backend=biber
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
´

Comment: Now it works :)

Comment: @MoHoushmand Can you add the additional info to the question? Code in comments is pretty messy. What do you mean by *it works*?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think you were wrong. The package for LyX has three different templates, one for bibtex, one for bibtex8 and one for biber. So I think it was enough just to add the file ending, the .bib to the calls of addbibresource. (three packages were needed due to lacking support for biblatex in LyX)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I got the bundle of bitbucket. Three different templates? I bet there is even more around. The whole template business is a mess. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the messy comment, but I made a new .lyx file in the directory:     /classicthesis-LyX-v4.2_biblatex_biber

then I followed the advice of @MWE and added these following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\addbibresource{MasterCite.bib}
```

At the and of the .lyx document I generated the bibtex bibliography inside a lyx comment, then i added 
    \printbibliography 
inside a TeX code.

The instructions given in wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex about adding:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

in the preamble gave me errors. 
I also made sure that in Document >> Setting >> Bibliography, Default(numerical) was checked in citation style, and bieber as processor.

Regards 
Mo

Comment: If your template already contains a call to `biblatex`, you will get errors adding another call to `biblatex`. BTW: If you think the question is solved, you can accept your answer.

Comment: Mhh, there should be a check-mark next to your answer that you can click. But it could be that there is some waiting time imposed for self-answers before you can accept it.

Comment: There's no reason for the original template not to work. It has been made following  the exactly same instructions from wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex. Those were, in fact, made to follow how things have been set up for the LyX port of classicthesis template. There are three templates in the zip on bitbucket, the settings in their classicthesis-config.tex reflect the backend being used in LyX (biber, bibtex8 or bibtex). I advise you and anyone using classicthesis ask on the LyX users list http://news.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general for a better (or any) support for biblatex.